# MySQL Database normalization

Tags: mysql, enums, database-normalization

Should I implement a read database normalization (using join tables) or should I use the ENUM type for static or dynamic data?

For example:

I have a table `USER` with a `user_status`. Should I create a table a `status` table or I create a ENUM list with the statuses?

Thanks G

Answer (score 26, accepted):

IMHO, the enum extension makes it much easier to embed semantics into a table and also improves efficiency by:

1. decreasing the number of joins required for a query
2. reducing the number of open tables in the DBMS

The only downsides I am aware of is

1. the ENUM type is not implemented by other DBMS
2. if you choose to add additional values to the ENUM set at a later date, you are applying a DDL update - which may take a long time with a very large table

HTH

C.

Comment: Peformance test: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/01/24/enum-fields-vs-varchar-vs-int-joined-table-what-is-faster/

Comment: There are other problems with `ENUM`.  For one thing, all `ENUM` columns can take a special "unknown" value of the empty string (in addition to `NULL` if so permitted); moreover, this value will be used for any assignment of an invalid value unless a strict SQL mode is in use.  This can lead to unintended database inconsistency; also, if one actually has an explicit empty string value in the `ENUM` list, this can lead to tremendous confusion (as one must inspect the numeric value to determine which "type" of empty string is stored).

Comment: Furthermore, the implicit conversion to numeric values in numeric contexts can cause considerable confusion - especially if one attempts to use strings representing numbers as `ENUM` values.  The manual gives a good example of an `ENUM` list `('0','1','2')`: "*If you store `2`, it is interpreted as an index value, and becomes `'1'` (the value with index 2). If you store `'2'`, it matches an enumeration value, so it is stored as `'2'`. If you store `'3'`, it does not match any enumeration value, so it is treated as an index and becomes `'2'` (the value with index 3).*"

Comment: Finally, `ENUM` can cause confusion in sorting contexts as values are sorted according to their position in the `ENUM` list (whereas the expectation may be that values will be sorted lexicographically).  Whilst I wouldn't go as far as Chris Komlenic's [8 Reasons Why MySQL's ENUM Data Type Is Evil](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/), I certainly think his article is worth reading to understand the problems; and, given that joining properly indexed tables ought to be as (if not more) efficient than `ENUM`, I don't see the advantages as all that "real".

Comment: @eggyal: Thanks for the link - it's interesting, but seems to be a bit out of date.Regarding the 'unknown' value - unable to replicate this on 5.0.22 - could only make the value NULL (when allowed to by the table definition).

Comment: Regarding `implicit conversion to numeric values` - again unable to replicate. Trying to insert an integer value into an enum column gave a #1064 error when I tried it

Comment: Regarding `can cause confusion in sorting` - all languages I'm aware of with enum support either use the order of declaration as an indicator of sequence (C, Fortran, Java, MySQL), or treat the values as purely non-ordinal (i.e. nominal). If you explicitly need ordering based on the label rather than it's internal representation, this is not hard (ORDER BY concat(enumd)) - frankly anyone who doesn't know how their tools manage typing deserves everything they get ;)

Comment: Re the two issues you have been unable to replicate: do you have a strict SQL mode enabled?  Re the sorting issue, you are right both that most people *should* expect such behaviour *and* that there are workarounds - but such workarounds cannot use any index defined over the column and therefore may prove to be very costly.

Answer (score 1):

An other stuff to be considered...

An enum could only be updated thru a modification of the database structure elsewhere a linked table permits dynamic creation of record.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on architecture and many other factors.

For example, you do not allow reading/writing data except using stored procedures. In this case you can feel free use "tinyint" datatype. If you allow reading/writing with direct queries it should be better to use constraint i.e. ENUM to avoid improper statuses (if UI or back-end can put this "wrong" status of course) .

On the other hand (and it's possible) there can be changes in data flow and maybe you will need to add new statuses. In this case you you will need:
1) do nothing if you have static datatype;
2) do alter if you have ENUM.

So... my answer is: it depends on your application and your requirements.

Comment: You can enforce correct statuses by foreign key restrictions as well (using innodb tables.)

Comment: ... and create another one table. I think that "over-normalization" (to have one additional table for each status) is not a good approach in general.

Comment: Could you explain why not? There is no problem with having many tables at all. (And they do allow for extra flexibility such as adding editable descriptions to a status, or disabling one for new records while keeping it for old records.)

Comment: because they need "alters". It is not a problem for small table but great problem for a big ones.

Comment: what do you mean by 'alters'? Creating enums require an alter statement as well, but perhaps that's not what you mean?

Comment: I mean when you will apply any changes in logic/data flow (i.e. adding a couple of statuses) you will need to do alter on it column. When you do not use ENUM you do not need to do alter to add new status.